# HTML inner items suddenly disappear on adding Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been making a User Projects section, and I wanted the projects to be in a carousel. So I decided to import bootstrap carousels but my items suddenly disappeared on doing so. I'm coding on a tablet as I don't have a computer, so I don't even know for 100% that I closed the divs properly. Any help please? This is my code:

```
<div class="userProjects" id="userProjects"> <!--line number: 126-->
        <h1> User Projects </h2> <!--line number: 173-->
        <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="clockImg">
            <img class="rounded clockSS" src="" alt="JS Clock"> <!--line number: 165-->
        </div>
        <h2> JavaScript Clock </h2>
        <p class="lead leadTwo"> One of the very first projects that he recommends is a simple, easy to make                javascript clock.
        </p> <!--line number: 180-->
    </div> <!--fadeInUserProjects div closing...-->
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Sorry for bad indentation. Also I modified the Bootstrap css a little to try and fix it:

```
        .carousel-inner,
        .carousel-item {
            width: 100vw;
            position: absolute;
            left: -20%;
            height: 180%;
            color: white;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-inner, .carousel-item {
            width: 100vw;
            position: absolute;
            left: -20%;
            height: 180%;
            color: white;
        }
```

You're setting both of those classes to `180% height` is that intended? check on it.

Comment: Yes it was weird without that height. I just tried changing it and it's literally the same.

Comment: Check on which version of Bootstrap you're using & try to use the same code, Bootstra-5 or 4, this is one  of the common issue!

Comment: I'm using version 5.0